# jQuery slimScroll scroll bar with fixed height

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, slimscroll

I am using the rochal's jQuery plugin [slimScroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) to display a customized scrollbar. Is there a way to make the height of the scrollbar fixed, not autogenerated? I think that the `wheelStep` value must be generated, but don't know what to change. So, question is how to make a fixed size scroll bar.

Also I could use another plugin if this is imposible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is posible! To achieve this do the following:

After:

```
// sets border radius of the rail
railBorderRadius : '7px'
```

Add comma after '7px' and:

```
// Use a fixed height for the scroll bar
useFixedHeight : true,

// the fixed height of the scroll bar
fixedHeight : 50
```

Replace:

```
barHeight = Math.max((me.outerHeight() / me[0].scrollHeight) * me.outerHeight(), minBarHeight);
```

With:

```
if( o.useFixedHeight )
    barHeight = o.fixedHeight;
else
    barHeight = Math.max((me.outerHeight() / me[0].scrollHeight) * me.outerHeight(), minBarHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

i have try with a simple trick..

first add a class to scroll bar, by default it is 'slimScrollBar'

> > barClass :  'slimScrollBar_new'

```
<script>
    $('#scroll-content').slimScroll({
        size : '3px',
        alwaysVisible: true,
        barClass : 'slimScrollBar_new'
    });
</script>

<style>
  .slimScrollBar_new{
      height: 100px !important;
   }
</style>
```